# ¿Cuál es el modo más eficiente?

Tags: python, string, lista

me gustaría aprender sobre la eficiencia del código, como comprobar su rapidez. ¿Qué me podéis recomendar?

De hecho, estoy programando un generador de claves en python similar al siguiente código:

```
import random

class Test():

    def list_key_generator(self):
        ch_source = ['a', 'c', 'b', ]
        password_ch_list = []
        for i in range(0, 12):
            password_ch_list.append(ch_source[random.randint(0, (len(ch_source) - 1))])
        new_password = ''.join(password_ch_list)
        return  new_password

    def string_key_generator(self):
        ch_source = 'abc'
        new_password = ''
        for i in range(0, 12):
            new_password += ch_source[random.randint(0, (len(ch_source) - 1))]
        return new_password

test = Test()
print(test.list_key_generator())
print(test.string_key_generator())
```

¿Cómo puedo comprobar cuál de los 2 métodos es más rápido?

Comment: No tiene que ver directamente con la pregunta, pero si buscas eficiencia el primer código usando una expresión generadora o python `choices` en Python >= 3.6 deben ser en torno a x2 y x5 más más rápidos respectivamente. `"".join(random.choice('abc') for _ in range(12))` ó `"".join(random.choices('abc', k=12))`

Comment: La diferencia entre tus dos códigos es mínima, la concatenación de cadenas es ineficiente, pero como solo iteras 12 veces esa diferencia se neutraliza con la sobrecarga de las llamadas a `list.append` y `str.join`. si aumentas el número de iteraciones el código usando la lista ira progresivamente ganando más eficiencia frente al que usa concatenación de cadenas.

Comment: Por último, si es solo con fines didácticos no pasa nada, pero el módulo random no debe usarse jamás con fines relacionados con la seguridad como generar claves aleatorias. Ten en cuenta que se basa en la generación de números pseudoaleatorios. Para estos fines se debe usar el módulo [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/secrets.html#module-secrets).

Comment: No sabía comprobarlo, pero pensaba que la lista debería ser más rápida. Por otra parte, en este caso sí es por aprendizaje, pero investigaré el módulo que me recomiendas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Le tienes que pasar un código de inicialización que lo ejecutará una sola vez, en este caso puede ser `import random`. Y luego el código que quieres medir. Que será primero una de las funciones, luego otra. Luego le indicas el número de veces que quieres que lo ejecute. El resultado será los segundos que tarda en ejecutarlo ese número de veces.

**EDITO:** He añadido las opciones [que comenta @FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284562/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-modo-m%c3%a1s-eficiente/284565#comment523148_284562)

```
import timeit

codigo1 = '''ch_source = ['a', 'c', 'b', ]
password_ch_list = []
for i in range(0, 120):
    password_ch_list.append(ch_source[random.randint(0, (len(ch_source) - 1))])
new_password = ''.join(password_ch_list)'''

codigo2 = '''ch_source = 'abc'
new_password = ''
for i in range(0, 120):
    new_password += ch_source[random.randint(0, (len(ch_source) - 1))]'''

codigo3 = '''"".join(random.choice('abc') for _ in range(120))'''
codigo4 = '''"".join(random.choices('abc', k=120))'''

setup = 'import random'

print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=codigo1, number = 10000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=codigo2, number = 10000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=codigo3, number = 10000))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=codigo4, number = 10000))
```

Que a mi me devuelve

> 1.1609692349993566
>
> 1.153979344999243
>
> 0.7535866809994332
>
> 0.20470473200111883

Esos números son el número de segundos que tarda cada función en ejecutar 10.000 veces. Así que tus dos opciones originales son prácticamente iguales, la mejor opción es la segunda que comenta @FJSevilla: `''.join(random.choices('abc', k=120))`

Comment: muy interesante esta librería, ya tengo un punto de partida para seguir investigando.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de calcular el tiempo de ejecución es con la librería `time`, editamos el código así:

```
from time import time
```

Esto lo ponemos arriba para importar la librería
y editamos la parte de abajo así:

```
test = Test()
tiempo_inicial = time()

print(test.list_key_generator())

tiempo_final = time()
tiempo_ejecucion = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial

print(tiempo_ejecucion)
tiempo_inicial = time()

print(test.string_key_generator())

tiempo_final = time()
tiempo_ejecucion = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial

print(tiempo_ejecucion)
```

Después de hacer varías ejecuciones los metodos tienen practicamente el mismo tiempo de ejecución, aunque a veces el segundo puede ser un poco más rapido, asi que si hay que dejar uno sería el segundo.

Comment: excesivamente complicado, teniendo en cuenta que existe la librería `timeit`